# Why is this code throwing an 'InvalidOperationException' when looping a list?

Tags: c#, error-handling, invalidoperationexception

I'm receiving an `InvalidOperationException` when iterating over the following loop.

```
foreach (LetterPoint word in NonIntersectingWordsLocations) {
        if (IntersectingWordsLocations.Any(item => item.Position.X == word.Position.X && item.Position.Y == word.Position.Y && item.Letter == word.Letter)) {
            NonIntersectingWordsLocations.Remove(word);
        }
    }
```

At that point in the code, `IntersectingWordsLocations` contains a total of `12` elements and `NonIntersectingWordLocations` contains a total of `57` elements. Both lists contain **NO** invalid or null elements.

One of these list elements looks like the following in the list: `{(LETTER:R, POSITION:(X:1Y:2))}`

Here is the class I am using for the list...

**LetterPoint.cs**

```
public class LetterPoint : LetterData<Point>, IEquatable<LetterPoint> {
    public Point Position {
        get { return Item; }
        set { Item = value; }
    }
    public LetterPoint(char c = ' ', int row = 0, int col = 0) {
        Letter = c;
        Position = new Point(row, col);
    }
    public string PositionToString => $"(X:{Item.X}Y:{Item.Y})";
    public override string ToString() => $"(LETTER:{Letter}, POSITION:{PositionToString})";

    // TO USE THE .COMPARE FUNCTION IN THE MAIN FILE
    public bool Equals(LetterPoint other) => Letter == other.Letter && Position == other.Position;
}
```

Why am I recieving this error?

**EDIT:**
The error message I am receiving is..

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation
>   may not execute.

Comment: You mean the exception message that tells you *specifically* that you're not allowed to modify the collection while you're iterating through it? (Not that we "know" this since you didn't include the text of the error in the question)

Comment: While the linked answer explains how to do it using a `for` loop, you might also use `List.RemoveAll(Predicate<T>)` to remove the items. If it's not a list, but implements `IList<T>`, then use a for loop and iterate backwards (from the last element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can not modify(delete or add elements) to a list during a for each operation on it,try use for loop instead.

Comment: It's important to note that `for` loop must be iterated in **reverse** for this to work properly (or the index must be decreased on each remove operation).